# Color distortion with Intel HD4000 over HDMI output - VGA is fine

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics, hdmi

I set up a new system with

- i5 3570k
- gigabyte z77 d3h
- using integrated graphics (HD4000)

and I've installed the 64bit Desktop version of 12.04. Connected to my Acer Screen via HDMI, the colors are horribly distorted. I think the biggest issue is that black appears as greenish. Over VGA everything is fine.

Interestingly, I once observed that connecting both, the VGA and the HDMI cable at the same time, solved the issue. Ubuntu thought 2 screens were connected, I mirrored the image, and over HDMI the colors looked fine. However, after a reboot I am now unable to reproduce this behavior.

I read frequently, that Intel hardware should be supported out of the box by Ubuntu but it doesn't seem to be the case here. Should I upgrade my Kernel? If so, which version would you recommend?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Just installed the Kernel version 3.6 and it fixed the problem.

So far no unwanted complications, but I've only been using it for 5 Minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue, except I am connecting it to a Samsung HD TV. If I don't set it to 1920 × 1080 the colors are fine, but things are blurry of course.

Comment: For me changing resolution does not solve the issue. Colors are still distorted.

Answer (score 0):

DELL support center said to me :  You have to upgrade your driver !
If I had a Windows 7 they could help me which new sofware would fix my problem because  DELL sell its computers officially not with Ubuntu !
I  have Dell 5720 laptop but I can not drive my SAMSUNG TV correctly . There is a picture :
always in two colors !!!  And my touchpad can not work with double-click after 5 minutes. I could only  click  with the left button !!
For the time being nobody could really help me to fix the above mentioned problems .

Answer (score 0):

I think it is this issue. Check the attached screen shots. Please can you also vote for this bug if it affects you!
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/751735